# What is the name of this cinematic boom

Tags: electronic-music

What is the name of this kind of soft, intense, [cinematic boom](https://openload.co/f/HBhmSpF00jE/Cinematic_boom.mp3)?

If it has no name, how could I reproduce it with any electronic music software?

Comment: Mild kick on the bass drum?

Comment: ... as opposed to an Earth-Shattering Kaboom

Answer (score -1):

That sound you are referring to is the sound of a distant firework exploding.

Answer (score -1):

That's a common low kickdrum hit, softened slightly to a nice, low thud. Most importantly though, some small, delayed ("gated") reverb has been added to give it that empty feel. Very satisfying but easily reproducible.

I'm not sure what I'd call it. If I was forced to categorize it, I'd call it a "soft-kick boom" or maybe "gated kick-drop" or "soft kick drop" as it has that big-drop feel but is still quite soft with the extended release being supplied by the reverb.

Simple to reproduce:

1. Use a simple kick sample or create a kick sound with a synth. Make sure it has plenty of clean low energy (i.e. not "muddy").
2. Attenuate the mid-high end either with an EQ or a Low Pass Filter.
3. Depending on the kick you used, you may need to soften the attack slightly.
4. Add reverb. Use a short to medium, delayed/"gated" reverb. Adjust this to suit.
5. You may need to remove some high-end from the reverb depending on the kick you used.

That's it really.